# How do I add a connection string as a protected section?

Tags: c#, sql-server, console-application

I need to deploy a solution that reads customer databases. I would like to secure the connection string to protect the password. All suggestions are at least 3 years old, some are 10 years old, on how to accomplish this. I have hit some errors, such as "This operation does not apply at runtime", "The configuration section must be added to a configuration hierarchy before you can protect it", and "Cannot add a ConfigurationSection with the same name that already exists".

The first error prompted me to create an external console application to adjust the configuration file of the original application. The second one made me think the code was in the wrong order. The final error is incredibly frustrating, as the original application's configuration does not contain the connection string. Below is the original application's configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Below is the code from the console application that is attempting to add a secure connection string.

```
try {
    Uri UriAssemblyFolder = new Uri(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase));

    string appPath = UriAssemblyFolder.LocalPath;

    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(appPath + @"\MyApplication.exe");

    ConnectionStringsSection section = new ConnectionStringsSection();

    section.ConnectionStrings.Add(new ConnectionStringSettings("LocalDB", @"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=master;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=sa;Password=the_password;"));

    section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");

    config.Sections.Add("connectionStrings", section);
    config.Save();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    printException(ex);
}
```

You can assume the console application is running in the same folder as the original application. To generate the second error, you can switch section.ConnectionStrings.Add with section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection.

I need to add a protected connection string that is defined after compilation. If this is impossible, do I have any alternatives? Placing a connection string file in a folder that only the original application can access?

Comment: Shouldn't you simply provide a configuration with an empty `<connectionStrings>` section, then load it, add the connection string, then protect it? Anyway, from whom are you protecting the connection string? It is trivial for the user running this application to decrypt it.

Comment: The empty <connectionStrings> section did work. My work would be installed in amusement parks and casinos, the data I am handling is not sensitive but they might have other sensitive data that I would be revealing. To be more specific, from whom am I protecting the data, I do not exactly know, but I am sure they exist and could very well be better programmers than me. If it is trivial to thwart this, do you think Windows access protocols is the proper way to secure the connection configuration, or do you have another suggestion? Should I just use Windows Authentication as the SQL credentials?

Comment: I now see that you can't even unprotect the section without saving it to disk unprotected. What is the point of this function, for emailing connection strings? This has been another wild goose chase trying to find helpful functions in a Microsoft stack.

Comment: I'm afraid that's because you're trying to solve an unsolvable problem. If you want to let a user use a service through your application, and that service requires a password of some sort, then **that user must be able to have the unencrypted password in-memory** at some point in time. So you can encrypt all you want; you're not _protecting_ that data in any way whatsoever. Instead, indeed, you couls use something like Windows Authentication, or a web service that hides the database. You then need the user to authenticate against the web service.

Comment: I am going to go with the Windows Authentication, the original application is running as a service so it is using the LocalSystem account. All I needs is read access so I think this should comply with most companies' security protocols.

Answer (score -1):

I am using this class

> just ensure your initial config is like that
>
> ```
> <appSettings>
>     <add key="connectionString" value="" />
> </appSettings>
> ```

```
public class SecureConfig
{
    private Configuration applicationConfiguration = null;

    public SecureConfig()
    {
        applicationConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    }

    public SecureConfig(Configuration config)
    {
        applicationConfiguration = config;
    }

    private static string EncryptString(string InputText, string Password)
    {
        RijndaelManaged RijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
        byte[] PlainText = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(InputText);
        byte[] Salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Password.Length.ToString());
        PasswordDeriveBytes SecretKey = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Password, Salt);
        ICryptoTransform Encryptor = RijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor(SecretKey.GetBytes(32), SecretKey.GetBytes(16));
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, Encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cryptoStream.Write(PlainText, 0, PlainText.Length);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        byte[] CipherBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();
        string EncryptedData = Convert.ToBase64String(CipherBytes);
        return EncryptedData;
    }

    private static string DecryptString(string InputText, string Password)
    {
        RijndaelManaged RijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged();
        byte[] EncryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String(InputText);
        byte[] Salt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Password.Length.ToString());
        PasswordDeriveBytes SecretKey = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Password, Salt);
        ICryptoTransform Decryptor = RijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor(SecretKey.GetBytes(32), SecretKey.GetBytes(16));
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(EncryptedData);
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, Decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        byte[] PlainText = new byte[EncryptedData.Length];
        int DecryptedCount = cryptoStream.Read(PlainText, 0, PlainText.Length);
        memoryStream.Close();
        cryptoStream.Close();
        string DecryptedData = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(PlainText, 0, DecryptedCount);
        return DecryptedData;
    }

    public string GetConnectionString(string password)
    {
        return DecryptString(applicationConfiguration.AppSettings.Settings["connectionString"].Value.Trim().ToString(), password);
    }

    public bool IsEmpty()
    {
        return String.IsNullOrEmpty(applicationConfiguration.AppSettings.Settings["connectionString"].Value.Trim().ToString());
    }

    public void SetConnectionString(String sConnectionString, string password)
    {
        applicationConfiguration.AppSettings.Settings["connectionString"].Value = EncryptString(sConnectionString, password);
        applicationConfiguration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        ProtectSection("appSettings");
    }

    private void ProtectSection(String sSectionName)
    {
        ConfigurationSection section = applicationConfiguration.GetSection(sSectionName);
        if (section != null)
        {
            if (!section.IsReadOnly())
            {
                section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
                applicationConfiguration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Which offers no additional security, whatsoever.

Comment: Yes, but this implementation does not do that. It offers no security over, say, ROT-13. Question: where do you store the password?

Comment: it can be hardcoded string ... yes it could be disassembled, but normal users do not have this ability